# How to create Qt-based Library That Can Be Called from C

Tags: c++, c, linux, qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to build a simple library that uses some of Qt's functionality (no event loop, just some image manipulation and file loading) and then call that library from a standard `C` program. I've reviewed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6533534), but the answer did not provide enough information for me to resolve the problem. I have built the library as a static library to be linked, and wrapped the function calls with `extern "C"`, but I get a bunch of errors, starting with `/usr/include/QtCore/qnamespace.h:-1: In function ‘QT_MODULE’:/usr/include/QtCore/qnamespace.h:54: error: unknown type name ‘namespace’.`

Does anyone have a short tutorial on linking to Qt libraries from a `C` program?  FYI, everything is under Linux (Fedora 15), and both the `C` program and the Qt library are being built with `QtCreator`.

Comment: Are you trying to include C++ headers from a C header? That won't work.

Comment: You can't simply include the Qt header files in your C program. You need to wrap the datatypes and classes inside your own structures, or use `void *` as suggested in the linked answer.

Comment: related to this: [wrap a c++ library in c? (don't “extern c”)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6047255/1025391)

Comment: The answer you linked says you must provide your own functions to access QT functionality. Have you done that?

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you want to make a wrapper for creating and deleting `QImage`, it could be done something like this:

In your header file:

```
typedef void *my_qimage_t;

extern "C" my_qimage_t my_create_qimage(int width, int height);
extern "C" void my_delete_qimage(my_qimage_t image);
```

And in your source file:

```
extern "C" my_qimage_t my_create_qimage(int width, int height)
{
    QImage *qimage = new Qimage(width, height);
    return static_cast<my_qimage_t>(qimage);
}

extern "C" void my_delete_qimage(my_qimage_t image);
{
    QImage *qimage = static_cast<QImage *>(image);
    delete qimage;
}
```

The `my_qimage_t` type is, from the callers perspective, a black box. All manipulation has to be done through your library, by passing this opaque pointer around.

Comment: Or you could declare `struct QImage;` in a C header, and avoid all these typedefs and unsafe casts.